# Polymer - Mixing iron-flex-layout and neon-animated-pages

Tags: css, polymer

I am building an app with Polymer. I am trying to layout my app using `iron-flex-layout`. In theory, it makes sense to me. However, practically, I can't seem to make it work with nested elements. Currently, I have the following:

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My App</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">    

    <script src="res/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script> 

    <!-- Polymer -->
    <link rel="import" href="res/components/polymer/polymer.html"> 

    <link rel="import" href="res/components/iron-flex-layout/classes/iron-flex-layout.html">
    <!-- End of Polymer -->

    <link rel="import" href="app.html"> 
    <link rel="import" href="page-home.html">
    <link rel="import" href="page-login.html">
  </head>

  <body class="fullbleed" style="background-color:lightcoral;">
    <div class="vertical layout">
      <div><h2>Hello</h2></div>
      <app-shell flex></app-shell>    
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The app.html referenced above looks like this:

**app.html**

```
<dom-module id="app-shell">
    <template>
        <style>
            :host {
                background-color:lightsalmon;                  
            }
        </style>

        <!-- Determine which view to load -->
        <h3>Enjoy!</h3>
        <neon-animated-pages flex id="pages" selected="[[selectedPageIndex]]" entry-animation="fade-in-animation" exit-animation="fade-out-animation">
            <page-home></page-home>
            <page-login></page-login>       
        </neon-animated-pages> 
        </div>                          
    </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'app-shell',
        properties: {
            selectedPageIndex: {
                type: Number,
                value: 0
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

And, just to provide an example of one of the pages, I have:

**page-home.html**

```
<dom-module id="page-home">
    <template>
      <style>
        :host {
          background-color:lightyellow;
        }
      </style>

      <div class="vertical layout center-justified">
        <h4>Welcome to My App!</h4|>
        <h5>I hope you like it!</h5>
      </div>                            
    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: "page-home"
        });
  </script> 
</dom-module>
```

The above code isn't behaving how I would expect. The colors don't align with the element hierarchy. In addition, the main content isn't centered vertically or horizontally at all. In an effort to learn how Polymer Elements work, I'm trying to create a layout that looks like this:

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
| Hello *                                       |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| Enjoy! **                                     |
+-----------------------------------------------+
|                                               |
|                                               |
|                                               |
|              Welcome to my App!               |
|              I hope you like it!              |
|                                               |
|                                               |
|                                               |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

I was expecting the part with one star (*) to be light coral. Then, the part with two stars (**) to be light salmon. Finally, the main part of the app to be light yellow. However, the whole thing is light coral. I do not understand what I'm doing wrong. Does `iron-flex-layout` just not work? Or is there something I'm totally missing here?

**Update:**
Below is kind of an update showing the addition of the mixin. Even with this mixin added, I still get an error in the chrome console that says: `/deep/ combinator is deprecated`.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style is="custom-style">
        .horizontal-layout {
            @apply(--layout-horizontal);
        }       
    </style>     
  </head>

  <body class="fullbleed" style="background-color:lightcoral;">
    <div class="horizontal-layout">
      <div>Item 1</div>
      <div>Item 2</div>
      <div>Item 3</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the mixins, as described in the fresh new blog entry from Polymer: https://blog.polymer-project.org/announcements/2015/12/01/deprecating-deep/

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't seem like the problem for me. Unless I'm somehow using it incorrectly. This just seems like such a straightforward problem. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: in the code you show us, the mixin is not applied... :)

Comment: I added an example to the question. I added the mixin and I'm still having problems.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: are you using the latest version of Polymer and its component?

Comment: I'm using Polymer: 1.2.3. Iron Elements: 1.0.5 and Paper Elements: 1.0.6